# Binding ICommand in Xamarin Forms Content View

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, icommand

I have a custom view which will be used across many pages.  I have a Close Button in the Custom View where I need to bind the CloseButton Command in my MainViewModel.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my HeaderView.xaml.cs file

```
public partial class HeaderView : ContentView
{
    public HeaderView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty CloseButtonClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CloseButtonClick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(HeaderView), null);
    public ICommand CloseButtonClick
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CloseButtonClickedProperty);
        set => SetValue(CloseButtonClickedProperty, value);
    }

}
```

Here is my close button code used in  HeaderView.Xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    HeightRequest="65"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="NameSpace.Views.HeaderView" x:Name="headerView">
            <Image  x:Name="CloseButton" Source="ic_closewhite.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseButtonClick, Source={x:Reference headerView}}"  />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
</ContentView>
```

Here is where I am trying to use the command in my MainView.xaml.

```
<c:HeaderView CloseButtonClick ="{Binding CloseButtonClickCommand}"/>
```

But it throws an error:
[image]

Comment: Can I take a look at your ViewModel?

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: Its my bad with compiling.  The code in my question works perfectly fine..!!! I recompiled again.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correct but only one small thing missing that is the x:Name of the ContentView HeaderView.
Just include this line of code in Xaml of HeaderView.

```
x:Name="headerView"
```

Here is your modified Xaml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    HeightRequest="65"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Name="headerView"
    x:Class="NameSpace.Views.HeaderView" x:Name="headerView">
            <Image  x:Name="CloseButton" Source="ic_closewhite.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CloseButtonClick, Source={x:Reference headerView}}"  />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its my bad with my compiling.  The code which I mentioned in my question works fine.  I just clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CloseButtonClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CloseButtonClick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(HeaderView), null);
```

the issue is on this line,as the error message said,

> event found for 'CloseButtonClick', or mismatching type between value
>   and property

you should change `CloseButtonClickedProperty` to `CloseButtonClickProperty` .

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CloseButtonClickedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CloseButtonClick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(HeaderView), null);
public ICommand CloseButtonClick
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(CloseButtonClickedProperty);
    set => SetValue(CloseButtonClickedProperty, value);
}
```

to

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CloseButtonClickProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CloseButtonClick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(HeaderView), null);
public ICommand CloseButtonClick
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(CloseButtonClickProperty);
    set => SetValue(CloseButtonClickProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its my bad with my compiling.  The code which I mentioned in my question works fine.  I just clean and rebuild.